# Commit file in svn with python3

Tags: svn, python-3.x

Is there any simple way to commit a file (.txt) that my script creates to svn?

I found a lot of tools but seems complicated to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to know which OS are you using before I answer this.

Anyway if you are using linux/unix you can use this:

Suppose all the files that need to be updated are stored in a file names.txt with absolute path.

```
import os
f = open('/root/names.txt')
line = f.readline()
f.close()
words= line.split()

for word in words:
    cmd1 = 'svn up ' +word
    if os.system(cmd1) == 0:
        print('All files updated')
```